# Question regarding change of variable in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I've been doing some work, and I am profoundly confused, hopefully the answer will put me at ease. Thing is, for example, I have a differential equation of the form
$$
\ddot{w}(z)+p(z)\dot{w}(z)+q(z)w(z)=0
$$
and I'm asked to do the change of variable kz, so we would have to compute
$$
\frac{d}{dz}w(kz)\quad\text{ and }\quad \frac{d^2}{dz^2}w(kz)
$$
and substite in our original equation. So far so good, my question arises when substituting on $p$ and $q$ (which are polynomials), my first inclination was to do $p(kz)$ and $q(kz)$ however an observation from my teacher was made: it is needed that the substitution on $p$ and $q$ be $\tfrac{1}{k}z$ instead, so it would be
$$
p\left(\frac{1}{k}z\right)\quad\text{ and }\quad q\left(\frac{1}{k}z\right).
$$
The result I was looking to achieved was achieved doing it this way, but why is the substitution on the polynomials different than on $w$ itself? Moreover, it appears that the inverse should be on the polynomials, I'm at awe at this.

And is this the general case?

Any help, insight or bibliography would be much appreciated, if a geometric point of view can be provided I would be even more grateful.

Comment: It really helps to change the letters, not use the same letter in two different roles and risking to mix up both roles in the same equation. Do you set $z=kx$ or $w(z)=u(kz)$? Both should result in different equations.

Comment: It would be more like z=kx, yes. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $z=kx$ and $k$ is a constant, if you replace $z$ everywhere you get
$$
u(x)=w(kx)\\
\dot u(x)=k\dot w(kx)\\
\ddot u(x)=k^2\ddot w(kx)
$$
so that inserted you get
$$
\frac1{k^2}\ddot u(x)+\frac{p(kx)}{k}\dot u(x)+q(kx)u(x)=0
$$
Now you could also replace $k$ by $k^{-1}$ to get another version of this formula that appears closer to what your teacher wanted to obtain.